# Equality of the arguments of complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

If $z_1$ and $z_2$ are two complex numbers such that $|z_1| = |z_2| + |z_1 - z_2| $then why is $arg(z_1) = arg(z_2)$ ?

Comment: $z_1>z_2$?......

Comment: @Dave sorry I’ll delete it

Answer (score 1):

Because the triangle with vertices $0,z_1,z_2$ has sides $|z_1|,|z_2|$ and $|z_1-z_2|$. The given equality makes the triangle degenerate (flattened), because in a regular triangle $|z_1|<|z_2|+|z_1-z_2|$. This is the triangle inequality. Therefore, $z_1,z_2$ and $0$ are co-linear. Moreover since $|z_1|$ is the longest side of the degenerate triangle, then $z_1,z_2$ point in the same direction.

By the way, $z_1>z_2$ is not necessary and probably makes sense only if $z_1,z_2$ are real.

Comment: Okay thank you , but how did you get the third side as $|z_1-z_2|$ ?

Comment: @Aditi Draw the picture...